# Create an Image out of a larger Image

Tags: java, image-manipulation

For a game I'm making I am storing all the sprites for the map inside one large(er) image. I want to be able to create an instance of `Image` for each image inside of the larger image that has all the sprites.

So how would I create an instance of `Image` from a set position of another `Image`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution (if all tiles in your tilesheet have the same size) is to use the `getSubimage(xpos, ypos, XSIZE, YSIZE)` method from the class `BufferedImage`.

Otherwise, you'll have to store a set of position and size for all sprites in another file.

Your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297426/whats-the-best-way-of-reading-a-sprite-sheet-in-java) others one.

Comment: `InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream( "/sprites/large.png" );`
`BufferedImage img  = ImageIO.read( stream );` 
`BufferedImage subImg = img.getSubimage( x, y, width, height );`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the java.awt.Image-class i am guessing you are trying to create a reasonable game using AWT? You really should take a look at a different technology like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL. The problem you ran into (partitioning a sprite-sheet) is typical for a lot of other problems (rotation...) you will run into if you try to develop a game without *something like* Open-GL.

Considering only the problem at-hand: you can easily solve this in Open-GL by binding the whole sprite-sheet as texture (glBindTexture()) and giving for each glVertex() a glTexCoord2f(), no need to cut-out parts of the sprite-sheet.

Comment: "Since you are using the java.awt.Image-class i am guessing you are trying to create a reasonable game using AWT?"  Why?  Can you name the Swing equivalent of Image or BufferedImage?  Once you go to custom rendering, it is pretty much 'AWT all the way' for either Swing or AWT based games.